# jQuery: Wrap parentheses and its content when a class is found in parentheses

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap code between parenthesis() if a specific class is found.

I am using a regex to highlight parenthesis.

```
var o = jQuery(".wp-site-blocks");
o.html(o.html().replace(/\([^\)]*?\)/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>'));
```

HTML looks like

```
(Some Text, 2022, 2021<span class="vbSup"><a href="#">11</a></span><span class="vbSup"><a href="#">12</a></span>)
```

But cant find a way to check if parenthesis have a specific class(.vbSup) in it then highlight otherwise ignore.

Its a long page with more than one parenthesis.

```js
$o = $(".wp-site-blocks p:has(.vbSup)");
$o.html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.replace(/\([^\)]*?\)/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
});
```

```css
.highlight{
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-site-blocks">

  <p>“Tragically, some 80% of the world’s hungry children live in countries with actual food surpluses, much of which is in the form of feed fed to animals which will be consumed by only the well-to-do consumers.”(Jeremy Rifkin, noted author of 23 books
    on the impact of global changes<span class="vbSup"><a href="#3af76716-b152-4705-a76f-f452228b13db" id="3af76716-b152-4705-a76f-f452228b13db-link">21</a></span>)</p>


  <p>“82% of the world’s starving children live in countries where food is fed to animals that are then killed and eaten by more well-off individuals in developed countries like the US, UK, and in Europe.” (Dr. Richard Oppenlander, 2012 Book )<span class="vbSup"><a href="#4bc2d108-83cb-49d4-918a-ea268c84b090" id="4bc2d108-83cb-49d4-918a-ea268c84b090-link">22</a></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see more of the html?  I'm wondering if this may be an [XY Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function as the replacement, so it can check whether the old contents contain `vbSup`.

```js
$o = $(".wp-site-blocks p");
$o.html((i, oldhtml) =>
  oldhtml.replace(/\([^\)]*?\)/g, (m) =>
    m.includes('vbSup') ? `<span class="highlight">${m}</span>` : m));
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-site-blocks">

  <p>“Tragically, some 80% of the world’s hungry children live in countries with actual food surpluses, much of which is in the form of feed fed to animals which will be consumed by only the well-to-do consumers.”(Jeremy Rifkin, noted author of 23 books
    on the impact of global changes<span class="vbSup"><a href="#3af76716-b152-4705-a76f-f452228b13db" id="3af76716-b152-4705-a76f-f452228b13db-link">21</a></span>)</p>


  <p>“82% of the world’s starving children live in countries where food is fed to animals that are then killed and eaten by more well-off individuals in developed countries like the US, UK, and in Europe.” (Dr. Richard Oppenlander, 2012 Book )<span class="vbSup"><a href="#4bc2d108-83cb-49d4-918a-ea268c84b090" id="4bc2d108-83cb-49d4-918a-ea268c84b090-link">22</a></span></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I thought you wanted to ignore when it has `.vbSup`.

Comment: PLEASE post a [mre].

Comment: Why not use Stack Snippet to post the code here, as I said above?

Comment: Both paragraphs there have `vbSup`

Comment: I've added a paragraph without `vbSup` to my snippet, and it doesn't highlight it.

Comment: I tried but now allowing me to save with Stack Snippet. First paragraph has vbSup inside () that is correct but the 2nd paragraph has vbSup after () so should be skipped.

Comment: I didn't realize `vbSup` has to be inside the parentheses. I'll rework the answer for that.